# How do I fix this authentication issue when using multitenant with Directus?

Tags: directus

I am trying to use Directus multitenant, but each time I try to switch tenant from the default `_` to lets save `acme` and try to log in, I get this error `[2018-12-15 19:35:13] api[layouts].ERROR: Directus\Authentication\Exception\InvalidTokenException: Invalid Authentication Token in /var/www/html/src/core/Directus/Util/JWTUtils.php:36`